# How to set placeholder to a table filter?

Tags: javascript, css, filter, datatable, webix

I'm trying to add a placeholder in the Webix table filter like next:

```
columns:[
    { 
      id:"title",   header:["Film title", { 
        content:"richSelectFilter", // placeholder:"Select the movie..." doesn't work
      }], width:300 
    },    
    { id:"rating",  header:"Rating",    width:100 }
]
```

Sample: http://webix.com/snippet/cac752a6

This works for the usual richSelect widget, but I can't find a way to change config for the same table filter. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a code like next to set placeholder for the rich-select filter

```
columns:[
{ 
  id:"title",   header:["Film title", { 
    content:"richSelectFilter", inputConfig:{ placeholder: "text here" }
  }], width:300 
},
```

http://webix.com/snippet/58b054a2

or, if you want to change the placeholder dynamically

```
var select = $$("d1").getFilter("title");
select.define("placeholder", "Some text here");
select.refresh();
```

http://webix.com/snippet/bd31c1f6